# Cannot find table 0 in C#

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

Get following exception While updating a Sql table using C# (Ado.net)

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
> >     Additional information: Cannot find table 0.

Here is my code:

```
int x;
da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS SET ITEM_NAME=@ITEM_NAME,ITEM_DESCRIPTION=@ITEM_DESCRIPTION,VENDOR_NAME=@VENDOR_NAME,QUANTITY=@QUANTITY,RATE=@RATE,AMOUNT=@AMOUNT,INVOICE_NUM=@INVOICE_NUM,DATE=@DATE WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL", con);
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemName.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemDescription.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@VENDOR_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtVendor.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantity.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@RATE", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtRate.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmount.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@INVOICE_NUM", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtInvoice.Text;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[bs.Position][0];
con.Open();
x = da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

if (x >= 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Record(s) has been updated");
}
```

Can anyone explain the solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciable

```
da.Fill(ds);
dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: There is no table in your dataset `ds`. If you want more insight of this then share how `ds` is getting filled.

Comment: As @Sachin has said, we need to see more code surrounding your dataset - how are you initializing it?

Comment: Dataset ds = new Dataset();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the meaning of da? is this your sqlcommand? if yes then try to use this hope it helps

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
Dataset ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

when im using MS SQL Server i do something like this

```
   sqlConnection.Open();
   sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "your SQL Statement";

   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[0];
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[1];
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[2];
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
   Dataset ds = new DataSet();
   sda.Fill(ds);
   dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
```

Comment: what dbms you are using?